# Санки ледянки / санки-ледянки

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`1. Сапоги снегоходы / сапоги-снегоходы.`

`2. Санки ледянки / санки-ледянки.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Санки-ледянки***, ***сапоги-снегоходы***.

Перед приложением нужен дефис.

Comment: А если это названия в магазине, то есть разница?

Comment: @Sharon Разница в чем?

Comment: Можно написать: сапоги "Снегоходы",  санки "Ледянки".

Comment: @Sharon Можно, если _снегоходы_ — это как бы фирменное название товара.

Comment: Это этикетка в магазине,  Как написать?

Comment: @Sharon Если это этикетка, то кавычки, то есть ваш вариант, в принципе, уместны.

Comment: Я не знаю, может Лео как раз сейчас и думает, как ему правильно оформить этикетку)

Comment: @Sharon Думаю, нет, у него же не было варианта с кавычками. Он, скорее, именно приложение и имел в виду.

Comment: Про кавычки он забыл)

Comment: @Sharon Конечно, возможно, но маловероятно) Даже если так, прочитает комментарии)

Comment: Ну ладно, пусть читает...)

Comment: Просто я думал, что *ледянки* — это как бы вид саней, из-за чего дефис не надо было бы.

Comment: Нужен контекст, а то задача получается неопределенной. САнки ледянки мне нужны, мне нужна  доскА ледянка. Здесь вроде раздельно. Как думаете, совчонки?